# how to make a windows python file executable in android

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, qpython

I have a python script which I wrote in windows OS and I am doing .exe file with py2exe and it is working fine in any windows PC ,but Now I want to run script or .exe in file in Android and widowsCE is it possible? And how can I convert script to work in Android or WindowsCE with out rewriting.
Please give your answers with any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus

Or you can search SL4A (Scripting Layer For Android) for more information.

Comment: Hi Jimmy thank you for your replay,I have used this Qpython and iam able to write sample programs, but I want android compiler to create .exe using py2exe in windows and run that .exe file in Android