# Make Python script excutable(Create exe) in all OS like Linux, WindowsCE, Android

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, windows-ce, py2exe

improving the question of  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282336/how-to-make-a-windows-python-file-executable-in-android)

I have python script file which i wrote in windows 7 and I am able create exe file of it using py2exe it is running fine in windows not in other OS. Now I want to create exe of that python script to run in all OS like Android, Linux, WindowsCE. Is there any possibility to do it? If yes, please explain step by step with example instead of posting ref-links.

Comment: Look at PyInstaller. You're not going to get one executable to rule them all, but you could eventually build an EXE for each platform.

Comment: You mean to say same script but need to create exe for each OS...?

Comment: Yes, I believe PyInstaller will only build native applications (meaning build a binary for the platform it is running on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at some existing python applications which are packaged for multiple platforms.  [Miro TV Application](https://github.com/pculture/miro) is a great example.  Check out the relevant portions of setup.py for:

- [OSX](https://github.com/pculture/miro/blob/master/tv/osx/setup.py#L86)
- [Windows](https://github.com/pculture/miro/blob/master/tv/windows/setup.py#L150)
- [Linux](https://github.com/pculture/miro/blob/master/tv/linux/setup.py)